# что значит expected comma в package.json

Tags: html, css, json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовала делать пробелы, отступы, ничего не помогло, в чем проблема?
package.json страшная штука)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После второй строчки нужна запятая, т.к. в объекте пара ключ-значение отделяется от другой пары именно так

Comment: Да, уже поняла, спасибо!